# How to code a constraint in Gurobi python

Tags: python-2.7, gurobi

I am so new in python and Gurobi!
recently I started to code a problem and I need to code this constraints:

```
for each i and j (while i is not equal to j):
(y[i][j]) * (D[i] - d[i][j])) <= T
```

Also I tried to start with not considering the equal part and wrote:

```
for i in people:
     for j in people:
          m.addConstr((carpools[i][j])*(distance[i]-distBtw[i][j])) <= 400
```

but I received this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a syntax error. You need your `<=` inside the addConstr:

```
for i in people:
     for j in people:
          m.addConstr((carpools[i][j])*(distance[i]-distBtw[i][j]) <= 400,
      name = '%s_%s_constraint'%(i, j)
)
```

FYI your multiplication in there is gonna give you a quadratic constraint which can make it very difficult for gurobi to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. about that quadratic constraint D[i] and d[i][j]s are parameters and y[i][j] is a binary variable, so I guess it is linear so.